# Why most of the distributed computing abstraction is built on fail-stop abstraction?

Tags: computer-science, computer-science-theory

I'm very curious about why most of the distributed computing abstractions are built on the fail-stop abstraction model which is composed of the `crash-stop process abstraction`, `perfect link abstraction`, and `perfect failure detector abstraction`. Why not built on the fail-recovery abstraction which is more similar to the real world which, I thought, is composed of `crash-recovery process abstraction`, `logged perfect link abstraction`, and `eventually perfect failure detector abstraction`.

For example, the `perfect failure detector abstraction` is based on the `synchronous system` while the real world is more like the `partial synchrony`. Why not we build higher-level abstractions on top of something like `partial synchrony`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a high level philosophy question and not a programming problem, maybe better for computer science?

Comment: Sorry for the off-topic question, do you mean I should revisit the tag and change them to `computer science` or ask the question on some suitable platforms?

Comment: I believe http://cs.stackexchange.com is the appropriate venue.